# Select text in html table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have an HTML table with a "select_tag" field and I want to have another field that receives the option selected then multiply by another number for the price to display the total. Here is the table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>(select_tag)</td>
        <td>price</td>
        <td>total</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How would I do this?

Comment: mutliply the price captured by what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is similar to @pythonFoo's but I've assumed a static price and separated the JS from HTML:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="quantity">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>price: <span id="price">$2.50</span></td>
        <td>total: <span id="total">$2.50</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript (again, assumes the value in 'price' is constant and you're just choosing 'quantity'.  If this isn't the case, please clarify your question):

```
var quantitySelect = document.getElementById("quantity");
var priceStr = document.getElementById("price").innerHTML;
var price = parseFloat(priceStr.substring(1), 10);

quantitySelect.onchange = function() {
    var quantity = parseInt(this.value, 10);
    var total = document.getElementById("total");
    var computedTotal = price * quantity;

    total.innerHTML = "$" + computedTotal.toFixed(2);
};
```

You would include the JavaScript in the `<head>` tag of your page, under a `<script type="text/javascript">` tag.

See a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/agepm/

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand multiply by what, but if you want to multiply by a quantity how "total" suggest, this code should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
price = [];
price[0] = 10000;
price[1] = 20000;
price[2] = 30000;
price[3] = 40000;
</script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><select id="select" onchange="document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = price[document.getElementById('select').value]; document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = price[document.getElementById('select').value] * document.getElementById('qt').value; ">
  <option value="0">Volvo</option>
  <option value="1">Saab</option>
  <option value="2">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="3">Audi</option>
</select></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="qt" onchange="document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = price[document.getElementById('select').value] * document.getElementById('qt').value;" value="1">
    </td>
        <td id="price">Price</td>
        <td id="total">total</td>
    </tr>
</table
```

In the array price, there are the prices. In the selectbox select the items with the id of the array and in the inputbox there is the number of items. It's basic, so it don't do controls on the value.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, see my [Calctastic](http://phrogz.net/JS/Calctastic/) library (originally written over 7 years ago!). The first example uses a select and automatically updates another field as it changes.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/3bRGm/) is the simplest way I could think off...my function supports multiple TR and don't rely on IDs or jQuery...etc (Even though I would prefer jQuery)